# jQuery Select Element Whose Parent is not Hidden by Hide()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="myContainer">
 <div id="containerHeader">
  ...
 </div>
 <div id="containerBody">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="titleInput"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

I hide it using `$("#myContainer").hide()` from the page. In it's place, on the same page, I display another component that is also using the same HTML (myContainer) with same ids and it's visible on it.

I want to select the child element (input) of the div element (myContainer) that is not hidden.

I have tried using `$("#titleInput:visible").val()` but it still gives me the value (empty) of component that is hidden. I could not figure out how can I get the value of the child component whose parent has not been set to hidden. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use vanilla javascript instead of jquery.

Comment: you should never user the same ID more then once. It's not valid HTML and always makes trouble.

Comment: basically, it's a view component in asp.net core mvc. that view component is being re used. One is hidden and another one is invoked in it's place.

Comment: You are right @caramba, even thought it's a view component, ID should not be the same (specially when one component is hidden and one is visible). Switching to class name resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to select the child element (input) of the div element (myContainer) that is not hidden.

```
$("#myContainer:visible input")
```

will select *any* input inside `#myContainer`, provided that `#myContainer` is visible on the page. See: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is the right thing to do but in my case, it was the issue with two components having the same id (one hidden and one visible) as mentioned in the comment by @caramba

Comment: @GMDev Assume you would be somebody who reaches this thread via Google search, and the question title reads *"jQuery Select Element Whose Parent is not Hidden by Hide()"* ... I'd say if it answers that question, it counts.